# Crashlytics doesn't report crashes

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have an app and I'm using Answers and Crashlytics plugins from Fabric. It allows me to see statistics and data from the dashboard (online and mobile) and lets me define new events for my app, but it doesn't report crashes!

I have these lines at the beggining of my MainActivity:

```
final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
            .kits(new Crashlytics())
            .debuggable(true)
            .build();
    Fabric.with(fabric);
    Fabric.with(this, new Answers());
```

And I also have these lines in my Application class, that extends from `Application`:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Answers());
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

Why isn't it working? I've done all the appropiate imports and I have both plugins installed in my Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! The solution was deleting those 2 lines in my Application class, and the last one that says `Fabric.with(this, new Answers());`, because Crashlytics has answers implemented by default so it's not necessary.